# How to use data of one jsp file into another

Tags: java, jsp

I am new in java. By using this loop i generated data in my demo2.jsp file

//it is demo2.jsp

```
 String sLabel
 String labelNames[]=request.getParameterValues("name");
   for(String str: labelNames)
   {
       out.println("<br>");
        sLabel=str;
      out.println(sLabel);
  }
```

by this i get output :-> software hardware(It is name of checkbox of demo1.jsp)

demo1.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="demo2.jsp">
<input type="checkbox" id="software" name="name" value="software"/>software<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="hardware" name="name" value="hardware"/>hardware<br>
```

I want to use that output(software, hardware) in another jsp page from demo2.jsp. for that i already created one form for POST action

//it is form of demo2.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="demo3.jsp">
<table>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</form>
```

In demo3.jsp how should i use output of demo2.jsp is there any kind of JSP inheritance available.
Please help?

Comment: You should have form submit on demo1.jsp and you can pass those values on demo3.jsp as a parameter. There is no need of demo2.jsp

Comment: going from one jsp to another isn't a great design. I would be good if you canlearn creating http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: use request,setParameter() , set the values in demo2.jsp . you can recieve itin demo3.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Use JSP file include to have the same functionality at different JSPs.

```
<%@include file="demo2.jsp" %>
```

in demo3.jsp